# Unable to Sync Movies to iPad

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, tv.app

I just upgraded our iPad Pro to 10.2 and noticed it the video app was replaced by TV app. I seem to have lost all videos synced from iTunes to my iPad. I tried deleting and reinstalling the TV app and also resyncing the videos through iTunes but no luck.

They show up in the storage used but no way to access them. They are supposed to be available in the Library of the TV app but my Library page is completely blank with no options.

Answer (score 1):

The TV app currently cannot accept video content synced from iTunes. There are 2 explanations:

1. iTunes itself needs an upgrade to understand that videos should be synced to the TV app instead of the Videos app
2. Apple has decided that you should not be able to sync video content from the iTunes app at all, only download from iTMS or stream from approved providers.

I think it is the first one. This is a bug which hopefully Apple will resolve soon with an update.

In the meantime, just install the VLC app (free) on your iPad. By connecting the device to your computer and using iTunes to transfer home videos to VLC on your iPad for viewing.